# Can we only use one value of any property in all screen resolutions of media query?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
    
    
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    
    html{
        font-size: 20px;
        max-width: 767px;
    }
    
    .main-nav li{
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .main {
        margin: 0px auto;
        padding-top: 4px;
        font-size: 65%;
    }
    
    h1{
        font-size: 120%;
    }
    
    .welcome {
        position: absolute;
        width: 767px;
}
    .p1{
        color: white;
        font-size: 10px;
        transform: translate(5%, 10%);
        margin: 0;
}
    
.section1 {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(93, 91, 91, 0.67), rgba(93, 91, 91, 0.67)), url(img/patrick-tomasso-71909-unsplash.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 1023px) {

    .welcome {
        font-size: 120%;
        width: 1023px;
}

    .sec-1{ margin-left: 30px; }

    .sec-1-ul li a,
    .sec-2-ul li a,
    .sec-3-ul li a {
        font-size: 80%;
    }   
    
    .p1{
        margin: 10%;
        color: white;
        font-size: 100%;
        transform: translate(5%, 10%)
}
    
    
    
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
   .section1 {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(93, 91, 91, 0.67), rgba(93, 91, 91, 0.67)), url(img/patrick-tomasso-71909-unsplash.jpg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center; 
        height: 70vh;
    }
    
    .logo{
        margin-left: 5px;
    }
    
    .p1{
        font-size: 150%;
        transform: translate(0%, 0%);
        max-width: 100%;
}
    
    h4{
    font-size: 120%;
}
    
    .sec-1,
    .sec-2,
    .sec-3{
        margin-top: 0px; 
}
    
    .sec-1-ul li a,
    .sec-2-ul li a,
    .sec-3-ul li a {
        font-size: 90%;
    }   
    
    
    h3{
    font-size: 120%;
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    }
    
}
```

I am new in web development.  I am using media queries for responsive web development. I have defined 4 screen widths in my file. But if I have defined value of any css property in one width, I can not change it in other width. For example if font size of one heading in 1200px is 80px, I am unable to change it to 40 px at 1023px and remains same. What is the error?

Comment: How are your media queries written? I suspect something in your logic there is not right. Please post your CSS.

Comment: I have posted my code

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort your media queries the other way round if you use max-width: First `max-width: 1200px`, then 1023px, then 767px.

The way you have them now the rules in the last media query will always overwrite the preceding ones since also the order is relevant (later ones will overwrite earlier ones), and `max-width: 1200px` also applies to the smaller widths. If you turn them around that will not happen.